# An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500). Calling the endpoint from lambda+ api gateway

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

My sagemaker endpoint seems to be working while calling from lambda function but when I am using same payload from api gateway rest api (rest api deployed on api gateway as ANY Method with LAMBDA API INTEGRATION ENABLED), it is giving following error

Part of lambda function code from where I am calling SageMaker Endpoint

```
@app.post("/dept_predictor")
@tracer.capture_method
def dept_predictor():
    # post_data: dict = app.current_event.json_body
    # try:
        print("Received event: " + json.dumps( app.current_event.body, indent=2))
        payload = app.current_event.body
        print(payload)
        # raise Exception('Malformed input ...')
    
        response  = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, 
                                                  ContentType='application/json', 
                                                  Body=json.dumps(payload),
                                                  Accept='Accept')
        print(response)
```

Lambda function CloudWatch log after calling lambda function from api gateway

```
[ERROR] ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

SageMaker Endpoint Cloudwatch log

```
2023-01-19T00:14:05.961+05:30   Loading the hash vectorizer model ...

2023-01-19T00:14:05.961+05:30   2023-01-18 18:44:05,959 ERROR - sklearn_functions - Exception on /invocations [POST]

2023-01-19T00:14:05.961+05:30   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/ml/code/sklearn_functions.py", line 130, in input_fn pname = json.loads(request_body)["product_name"]

2023-01-19T00:14:05.962+05:30   TypeError: string indices must be integers

2023-01-19T00:14:05.962+05:30   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

2023-01-19T00:14:05.962+05:30   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 200, in transform self._model, request.content, request.content_type, request.accept File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_transformer.py", line 227, in _default_transform_fn data = self._input_fn(content, content_type) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 95, in wrapper six.reraise(error_class, error_class(e), sys.exc_info()[2]) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/ml/code/sklearn_functions.py", line 130, in input_fn pname = json.loads(request_body)["product_name"]

2023-01-19T00:14:05.962+05:30   10.32.0.2 - - [18/Jan/2023:18:44:05 +0000] "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "AHC/2.0"

2023-01-19T00:14:05.962+05:30   sagemaker_containers._errors.ClientError: string indices must be integers
```

I tried to check this similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/235) which is not resolved yet.
Any lead on this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. When I am calling from using api gate rest api same payload is getting transfer without using lambda api proxy integration and ANY method setup as string. So converting string payload to dict payload solved the issue

```
payload = json.loads(payload)
```